# Условие в значении свойства JSON

Tags: json, rest

Я создал JSON используя [Survey Creator](https://surveyjs.io/create-survey/):

```
{
 "pages": [
  {
   "name": "page1",
   "elements": [
    {
     "type": "radiogroup",
     "name": "question1",
     "choices": [
      "item1",
      "item2",
      "item3"
     ]
    },
    {
     "type": "text",
     "name": "question2",
     "visibleIf": "{question1} = \"item1\""
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

В зависимости от значения свойства `visibleIf` должен скрываться или показываться вопрос `question2`.
Что значит `{question1} = \"item1\"` в значении свойства `visibleIf`. Как это выразить в MySQL базе данных, чтобы получить это условие в свойстве `visibleIf` объекта JSON? Какой тип поля? Как это будет работать?

Comment: как связан приведенный JSON с базой MySql? Почему весь его не хранить в одном поле?

Comment: Мне нужно передать фронтендеру приведенный json. Его нужно сформировать выборкой из БД. Имеете в виду json тип поля с содержимым `{"visibleIf": "{question1} = \"item1\""}`? Но я не понимаю как это будет работать. Поиск не помог.

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду что в поле хранится **весь** приведенный в вопросе json. тип поля вполне может быть обычным `varchar(max)`

Comment: Этот вариант не подходит. Однако что насчет `visibleIf`? Мне нужно указать `"{name} = \"value\""}` (varchar) для каждого вопроса? Но как это будет работать? То есть я понимаю, если бы это выглядело так 
    `"visibleIf": {
     "name":"question1",
     "value":"item1"
    },`. Но не понимаю вариант, указанный выше.

Comment: почему этот вариант не подходит?

Comment: нужно разработать админку с возможностью редактировать поля в бд.

Comment: пока не вижу противоречий

Comment: Хорошо! Я сделаю `varchar(max)` и помещу туда весь JSON. Но как понимать `visibleIf`?

Comment: зачем тебе его как-то понимать?